# How to fill columns with images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Consider I've a sample layout in bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
           <img class="filler" src="some/other/img.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
           <img class="filler" src="some/other/img.jpg" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <img class="main-img" src="some/link.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto" />
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I make images with `filler` class to auto-scale to gain the same **height** as the image with `main-img` class.

I want to reach the following effect:

```
 ________ ____________
|.filler |            |
|________|auto-scale  |
|.filler |width: 100% |
|________|____________|
```

Is that event possible only with css?

EDIT:
I meant a **height** not, *width* (my bad);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you didn't pay enough attention to the Bootstrap `HTML` markup which is quite important for it to remain "smart" and responsive.

```css
.filler, 
.main-img {
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="filler" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
    <img class="filler" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img class="main-img" src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/frontdoor/creative/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg" />
  </div>
```

---

After the lil' talk we had in the comments, decided to back what i said with some code. Done with jQuery, as it was faster (for me). If you don't already have jQuery in your project, you should probably rewrite it in javascript. Not fully tested, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work cross-browser, cross-platforms:

```js
document.initPictures = function() {
  $('.resizeMe').css({
    'height': $('#theContainer .col-sm-6').eq(1).height() + 6,
    'display': 'flex',
    'flex-direction': 'column',
    'transition': 'height .4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.55, 0.2)'
  });
  $('.resizeMe img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.resizeMe').append('<div style="flex-basis: 50%; background-image: url(' + src + '); background-size:cover; background-position: center center"' + '</div>');
    $(this).remove();
  })
};
document.resizePictures = function() {
  if ($('#theContainer').outerWidth() > 768) {
    $('.resizeMe').css({
      'height': $('#theContainer .col-sm-6').eq(1).height()
    });
  } else {
    $('.resizeMe').css({
      'height': $('.resizeMe').outerWidth()
    });
  }
};
$(window).resize(function() {
  document.resizePictures();
});
document.initPictures();
```

```css
.main-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
#theContainer {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-fluid" id="theContainer">
  <div class="col-sm-6 resizeMe">
    <img class="filler" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
    <img class="filler" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="main-img" src="http://joombig.com/demo-extensions1/images/gallery_slider/Swan_large.jpg" />
  </div>
```

**NOTE**: if anyone could explain to me why `$('#theContainer .col-sm-6').eq(1).height()` is `6px` smaller at page load than afterwards, I'd be really happy.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that: do you know what `width` means? You never said anything about height up until now. Please update your question so I can understand what you want. Try to be specific. Thank you.

Comment: Ahh sorry, my bad. I meant the same height, just misplaced words.

Comment: So you want their combined height to be the same height with the one in the right side? That will clearly either distort the images or crop them. What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: No, what you want is not achievable via CSS, nevermind Bootstrap. You need to grab the actual height of the image in right column via javascript, set it as max-height of the left column, set left column display as flex with flex-direction: column. Besides, for resizing and cropping the pictures in this left column you'd want to give them visibility hidden and put them in the background of a wrapper, with background-size cover. Sounds complicated? It kind of is. :) And I'm still not sure it would behave nicely for various proportions of the three images.

Comment: Added a toy to response. Enjoy! :)